# Hatcher algebraic topology book prop. 2.29

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am studying algebraic topology from Hatcher book and i don't understand the first sentence of proof of proposition  2.29. on page 135 ,

***Proposition  2.29***.  $ \mathbb{Z}_2$ is the only nontrivial group that can act freely on $S^n$ if $n$ is
even  .

**Proof:**      Since the degree of a homeomorphism must be ±1 ,an action of a group G
on Sn determines a degree function  .

I can't see why degree of a homeomorphism must be ±1 .If it has other degree different than  ±1 it will be contradiction with free action on $S^n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the free action of a group. The degree of a homeomorphism can only be $\pm 1$ because a homeomorphism induces an isomorphism on the homology, and since $H_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, the only automorphisms of $H_n(S^n)$ are the identity and the multiplication with $-1$.

Comment: Ahh yes it is simple thanks i can't think it induces the isomorphism